# How do I match patient data for conditional logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a dataset as below:

```
 patient_id   pre.int.outcome post.int.outcome 
  302949               1            1            
  993564               0            1           
  993570               1            1   
  993575               0            1    
  993792               1            0
```

I want to perform clogit pre/post intervention for each patient

I understand that I need to get it into the form:

```
  strata            outcome
   1                 1
   1                 1
   2                 0
   2                 0
   3                 0
   3                 1
```

In this form, the strata are the pairs of patient numbers, and the outcome, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone help or direct to a source that will help?

edit: what I eventually ended up doing was to use the reshape function to make the dataset 'long' as opposed to wide;

```
    ds1<-reshape(ds, varying=c('pre.int.outcome','post.int.outcome'), v.names='outcome', timevar='before_after', times=c(0,1), direction='long')
```

The I sorted by patient_id to use that as my 'strata'.

```
    ds1[order(ds1$patient_id),]
```

Comment: May be using `melt` from library(reshape2) i.e. `melt(df1, id.var='patient_id')[-2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this helps

```
data.frame(strata= rep(1:nrow(df1), each=2), outcome=c(t(df1[2:3])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Building upon akrun's comment and answer, here's a solution using the `reshape2` package's `melt`:

```
library(reshape2)

# I created dummy data to make sure my answer works
# I assumed 4 intervention treatments, but this would work with 
# two treatments. With the dummy data, just make sure nObs/4 is an integer
nObs = 100 # number of observations
d = data.frame(patient_id = 1:4, 
           pre.int.outcome = rbinom(4, 1, 0.7), 
           post.int.outcome = rbinom(4, 1, 0.5),
           intervention = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = nObs/4))
# melting the data as suggested by akrun  
d2 = melt(d, id.vars =  c("patient_id", "intervention"))

# Creating a strata variable for you with paste
d2$strata = as.factor(paste(d2$patient_id, d2$variable))
# I also clean up the variable to remove patient_id
# useful if you are concerned about protecting pii
levels(d2$strata) = 1:length(d2$strata)
# last, I clean up the data and create a third "pretty" data.frame
d3 = d2[ , c("intervention", "value", "strata")]
head(d3)
# intervention value strata
# 1            a     1      2
# 2            a     1      4
# 3            a     1      6
# 4            a     1      8
# 5            a     1      2
# 6            a     1      4
# I also throw in the logistic regression
myGLM = glm(value ~ intervention, data = d3, family = 'binomial')
summary(myGLM)
# prints lots of outputs to screen ...

# or if you need odds ratios
myGLM2 = glm(value ~ intervention - 1, data = d3, family = 'binomial')
exp(myGLM2$coef)
exp(confint(myGLM2))
# also prints lots of outputs to screen ...
```

**Edit:** I added in `intervention` based upon comments from the OP. I also added the `glm` to further help her or him.

Comment: Also, ["pii"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) is Personally identifiable information. I realized most people probably don't know that acronym. See the linked Wikipeida article if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: Is there a way to include 'pre' and 'post' as a row value in your solution ie: value, strata and intervention?

Comment: Yeah. That column is missing from the dummy, data correct? Assuming the column name is `intervention', you would change `melt` to be `melt(d, id.vars = c("patient_id", "intervention")`. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: @user1745691 if you're doing lots of this research, you might also want to check out the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package. It has lots of cool tools developed by Frank Harrell.